# How do I configure single table inheritance for three classes using Doctrine in YAML format?

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, orm

In a Symfony3 project, I already used "single_table" inheritance:

```
ADS\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomPage:
type: entity
table: custom_page
inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
discriminatorColumn:
    name: type
    type: string
id:
    id:
        type: bigint
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    content:
        type: json_array
        nullable: true
        length: null
        options:
            fixed: false
    creationdate:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
        column: creationDate
```

**for the second entity**

```
ADS\CoreBundle\Entity\ProductRangePublication:
type: entity
table: custom_page
manyToOne:
    productRange2:
        targetEntity: ProductRange
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            productrange_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
```

I want to use this again, but with two classes inherinting a parent class.
The parent would be the class "Etfresearch" and the children the classes "Document" and "Pages."
How could I do this? How to put two discriminators for two different classes in the same Doctrine configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `discriminatorMap` option to the parent class definition:

```
App\Entity\Etfresearch:
  type: entity
  inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
  discriminatorColumn:
    name: discr
    type: string
  discriminatorMap:
    etfresearch: Etfresearch
    document: Document
    page: Page
```

```
App\Entity\Document:
  type: entity
  #[...]
```

```
App\Entity\Page:
  type: entity
  #[...]
```

This maps "document" to the Document class for example, so rows in the database that have this as a value for the "discr" column will be identified as a Document and will be returned when you call
`$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Document::class)->findAll();`

Note that as "Document" and "Page" extend "Etfresearch," **all** rows of this table will be returned when you call `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Etfresearch::class)->findAll();`